# How to determine if OneDrive is in on demand mode?

Tags: onedrive

I need to determine if OneDrive is in On Demand mode programmatically. I'd think this was just a registry setting, but I've looked through the all of the keys under `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive` and nothing jumps out at me. Where can I find this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diff-ing the exported registry keys with the OneDrive On Demand feature both enabled and disabled, it looks like the key that holds this value is `LastKnownCloudFilesEnabled` under `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business1`. Hopefully this helps someone else out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Worth pointing out that you can't enable/disable the Files On Demand feature per-user by simply modifying this registry key. If you do change it, OneDrive will revert the registry change when it next starts.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked the registry after toggling Files On Demand, what changed for me was `UpdatedTenantValue` under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business1\Tenants`. On-Demand ON was `da8` and OFF was `da9`. As this is not documented by Microsoft, they could change the meaning in the future.